# vuetify extra margin <v-select>

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new in vuetify and having extra margin while displaying `<v-select>`'s.

As far as I tried the things mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1490). But adding `class="page-wrap application application--light" data-app="true"` to parent element of vue.js app  and removing `<v-app>` didn't work for me. Since the app that I am working on is very in very nested. I couldn't paste everything here.

Any suggestions I can try and also I couldn't understand the explanation in [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1490). `Due to how v-app works, the outer elements which contain margin are throwing off the calculations.`

Thanks[image]

Comment: I suggest you [provide codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com) which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The project that I am working on is very big, this is a very small individual Vue app which resides in the main .net app. I know there is outside CSS(maybe layout file or another global CSS file in the project)affecting the position of the v-select. So the example I paste to codepen works okay. I feel that I need to exclude this small Vue app from the rest of the .net application @Traxo

Comment: try to change the position and the size of the parent element ,

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim unfortunately, didn't work. outside sourced margin still causing the same issue. when I do  `* { margin: 0 !important; }` that helps to align the dropdown be shown right under the place but that time it removed all margins from the component